# How to get the icon associated with a corresponding file type?

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in android. My android Emulator SD Card contains lot of folders and files. These file extensions are (*.txt, *.doc, *.pdf, *.xml, *.png, *.bmp, *.jpg, etc). How to get and set corresponding file type icon. If it is possible please send information. Otherwise if it is not possible send Reason. Please reply, Your comments and answers all are valuable me. Thanks.